# Issues trying to bootstrap Chef for windows client with knife-windows

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am having some problems trying to bootstrap a windows node for Chef. This node was initially able to be partially bootstrapped, it was getting through most of the process but however, failing near the end - on the windows client itself I can see a number of expected files under `C:\Chef`

However since upgrading my Ruby and Knife-Windows to remedy the original issue - I am now not able to bootstrap at all, I get the error below:

```
chefadmin@AUK-CHEFMGT1:~$ knife bootstrap windows winrm 10.28.154.61 -x chefadmin -P xxxxxx

/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.5.1/lib/chef/mixin/path_sanity.rb:25: 
warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777


Waiting for remote response before bootstrap.10.28.154.61 . 
10.28.154.61 Response received.
Remote node responded after 0.01 minutes.
Bootstrapping Chef on 10.28.154.61
ERROR: RuntimeError: Knife-Windows < 1.0 does not support validatorless bootstraps
```

I've tried a few different versions of knife-windows, initially `1.1.1`, and most recently the pre-release version of `1.0.0 rc1`, however, they are all giving me this error.

I am not sure why this is a problem, as the `validation.pem` does exist on the windows client in `C:\Chef\`

In case it matters, here is my `knife.rb` config file:

```
chefadmin@AUK-CHEFMGT1:~$ 
GNU nano 2.2.6    File: /home/chefadmin/chef-repo/.chef/knife.rb 
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "chefadmin"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/ChefRSA.pem"
validation_client_name   "company"
validation_key           "#{current_dir}/companyvalidator"
chef_server_url          "https://10.28.253.101/organizations/company"
syntax_check_cache_path  "#{ENV['HOME']}/.chef/syntaxcache"
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"#{current_dir}/companyvalidator"` Does that file exist? Usually that would be something ending in `.pem`. If that path isn't a thing, it would fall back to new-style bootstrapping which I don't think works on Windows yet.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this was actually correct but upon reviewing it you were right, this needs to be a .pem file being specified, and it also seemed to me that keeping #{current_dir} was not working. I had to specify the full path, and went with the default of /etc/chef/company-validator.pem. So thanks for your help - thanks also to Wai Ha Lee for making my original post more legible. I now have another error but will make another post for that after I investigate further. Cheers all.